# capture previous state and store it in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an app where the user can hover over elements and the data associated with that element is stored in state. Right now the current element is stored but I need to also store the data from the last element hovered over.

I've tried following [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/accessing-previous-props-state-react-hooks/) and using a spread operator to make a deep copy but neither seem to work.

Here is what I currently have (`hovered` is brought in as a prop:

```
 const [nodeDetails, setNodeDetails] = useState();

  const prevNodeDetails = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    const clone = { ...hovered };
    setNodeDetails(clone);
  }, [hovered]);

  console.log(nodeDetails);
```

The use effect should update when

Comment: Do you have any minimal reproducible example of your code? Like codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

you need to actually set prevNodeDetails in useEffect i.e.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    prevNodeDetails.current = nodeDetails;  //here
    const clone = { ...hovered };
    setNodeDetails(clone);
}, [hovered]);
```

if you need a deep clone and the data is nested you can also use:

```js
const clone = structuredClone(hovered);
```

instead of:

```js
const clone = {...hovered};
```